# g++ (GCC) 4.6.0 I have the following class and I am trying to initialize structure member initialization list of my constructor

Tags: c++

g++ (GCC) 4.6.0

I have the following class and I am trying to initialize in my initialization list of my constructor.

```
class Floor_plan
{
private:
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;

    struct floor_size {
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
    } floor;

public:
    Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor.x(0), floor.y(0) {} {}
    Floor_plan(unsigned int _width, unsigned int _height, unsigned int _x, unsigned int _y);
    ~Floor_plan() {};
}
```

In the above code,

how can we initialize floor_size structure member without creating object of floor....
Thanks in advance for your answers....

Comment: You can't initialize something that doesn't exist. You need to create an instance.

Comment: besides that it is called ctor-initializer or mem-initializer-list, you can only initialize members of your own type, that is only members that are members of the Floor_plan class, not of any other class. Write a ctor for floor_size.

Comment: The member variable `floor` will be created automatically when an instance of the `Floor_Plan` class is created. There's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your struct `floor_size` is POD (Plain Old Datatype) so you can initialize `floor` member like this:

```
Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor()
{}
```

This will use one of zero-, default- or value-initialization, I never know which.

And if you enable C++11 support (`-std=c++0x` switch) you can use brace initialization:

```
Floor_plan() : width(0), height(0), floor({10, 20})
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use static keyword infront of struct floor_size, you can initialize by using the class name like this,

```
Floor_plan::floor.x=100;
Floor_plan::floor.y=100;
```

Comment: I think you're confusing Java and C++

Comment: refer the textbook "The complete reference c++ , Herbert schildt"

Comment: that book can say what it wants but you won't get this to compile on a C++ compiler it's `Floor_plan::floor_size Floor_plan::floor ={ 100,100};` for static initialization and even later for static access it's still "`::`" and not "`.`"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need not to initialize this structure. Simply define it as a type member

```
struct floor_size {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
};
```

And when you will need to reinterpret width and height as elements of floor_size you can create an object of floor_size as for example

```
floor_size floor = { width, height };
```

Answer (score 0):

Floor **is** already an object of "class"(or struct) **floor_size**.

You just need an constructor for intiliation.

For Example:

```
class Floor_plan
{
private:
    unsigned int m_width;
    unsigned int m_height;

    struct floor_size {
        unsigned int m_x;
        unsigned int m_y;
        public: floor_size(int p_x,int p_y) : m_x(p_x),m_y(p_y) {}
    } floor;


public:
    Floor_plan() : m_width(0), m_height(0), floor(0,0) {}
    Floor_plan(unsigned int _width, unsigned int _height, unsigned int _x, unsigned int _y);
    ~Floor_plan() {};
};
```